# TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class in Django tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am using Django 2.1.5 and pycharm.
When running tests from Pycharm I started getting this error:

```
File "/Users/..../lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 576, in _makeTest
if issubclass(parent, unittest.TestCase):
```

TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

I'm getting it only when trying to run one test (and not a test class).
Also getting it when trying to run it through

```
python manage.py test specific_test
```

I understand the error meaning, but I don't understand why I started getting it suddenly.

EDIT:

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
yield
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
testMethod()
File "/..../lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
File "/..../lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/nose/loader.py", line 523, in makeTest
return self._makeTest(obj, parent)
File "/..../lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 576, in _makeTest
if issubclass(parent, unittest.TestCase):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

the parent is

```
<function MyTestClass.test_function at 0x10ff32f28>
```

Comment: how does `specific_test` look like?

Comment: minimal complete reproducible example and full traceback please...

Comment: What is the `parent` variable?

Comment: Question Edited

Comment: show us your `specific_test` method (and the class to which it belongs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get this error when I don't properly point to the test I'm trying to run.

When I tried to run a specific test method I tried the following and got the error you mention: `./manage.py test myapp.tests.test_file.MyTestCase.test_something`

What I had to run to actually get it to work was: `./manage.py test myapp.tests.test_file:MyTestCase.test_something` (Notice the `:` between the file name and the class name)

I believe this issue is specific to 'nose'.

Comment: Exactly. That was the problem.

Comment: Anyone else use PyCharm and know how to automatically fix this?

Comment: @michaelsnowden you need to specify your test runner with `TEST_RUNNER = "django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner"` (or whatever your runner) in the `settings.py` you set up in `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Django` and not the one set up in your test/run config

Answer (score 0):

To fix this in Pycharm, you need to specify your test runner with `TEST_RUNNER = "django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner"` (or whatever your runner) in the `settings.py` you set up in `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Django` and NOT the one set up in your test/run config.

See comments on the following:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13479
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14536
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13479